# Symfony2 SubSelect in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I have little problem.

First of all. I have two entity:
Book ( no matter what it have )
Warehouse ( it have isAvailable field )

That two entities have relation ManyToOne (Many Books to One Warehouse )

I want to get all book which are in Warehouse and where isAvailable > 0

I know what I have to but I don;t know how to write it to QueryBuilder.

My simple code

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('b.name, b.slug, b.path, b.image')
            ->from('MGraphicsApplicationWebsiteCoreBundle:Book', 'b')
            ->leftJoin('b.bookWarehouse', 'bw');
```

How can I add/connect something likt that :

```
$qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('COUNT(bw)')
                ->where('bw.isAvailable = 1')
                ->andWhere('bw.book = ?')
```

Comment: I don't understand your database structure. Are the books individual books or book titles that can be present in several warehouses at the same time? Is the `isAvaliable` field about the availability of warehouses or books? Do you want to select all books that are available in at least one warehouse? Or do you want to select all books related to a certain warehouse?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all Books that belongs to **any** Warehouse, the `innerJoin` already do this for you:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('b, COUNT(b.id) AS books')
    ->from('MGraphicsApplicationWebsiteCoreBundle:Book', 'b')
    ->innerJoin('b.bookWarehouse', 'bw')
    ->where('b.isAvailable = 1');
```

If you want to fetch the Books of a **specific** Warehouse, just add a condition:

```
->andWhere('bw.id = :warehouse')
->setParameter('warehouse', $myId);
```